# SQL - I'm trying to find the average of all fields that meet a condition and I'm getting: invalid in the HAVING clause

Tags: sql, having, average

SQL - I'm trying to find the average of all fields that meet a condition and I'm getting: invalid in the HAVING clause...
Any help would be awesome.

```
use Pizza05
Select AVG(PizzaToppings.ToppingPrice + Products.ProductPrice) as Average
from OrderedProducts
Left Join PizzaToppings ON PizzaToppings.ToppingID = OrderedProducts.ToppingID
Inner Join Products ON Products.ProductID = OrderedProducts.ProductID
having OrderedProducts.QuantityOrdered > 10
```

Comment: Replace it with WHERE

Answer (score 2):

You should use `HAVING` to filter over grouped values, use standard `WHERE` to filter non-grouped fields.

Eg.

```
SELECT 
   AVG(T.ToppingPrice + P.ProductPrice) Average
FROM OrderedProducts O
LEFT JOIN PizzaToppings T 
   ON T.ToppingID = O.ToppingID
INNER JOIN Products P 
   ON P.ProductID = O.ProductID
WHERE 
   O.QuantityOrdered > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `having` with `where`, since `having` is used to specify conditions on aggregate functions, not single columns. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).